# Annihilator of a maximal ideal in a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let R be a ring and M a maximal ideal in R. Prove or disprove: If M is contained in the set of zero divisors of R, then ann(M) is not 0.

It is easy to see that the statement is true when M is a principal ideal.
But I don't know how to solve for the general case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this and tell me what happens in the finitely generated case?

Answer (score 4):

It's not true. Let $F$ be a field, $A:=F[X_1,X_2,\dots]$ the polynomial ring over $F$ in countably many indeterminates. Then taking $R:=A/(X_1,X_2^2,X_3^3,\dots)$ and $M:=(\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2,\bar{X}_3,\dots)$ gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

As Censi Li already showed (+1), that statement is wrong for a general commutative ring. However, adding the assumption that $R$ is *Noetherian*, it is true and follows from the [Prime Avoidance Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) together with the fact that the set of zero-divisors is the union of the set of [Associated Primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime)